# Chaining promise returning functions in Kovenant

Tags: kotlin, kovenant

I am trying to chain 2 promise returning functions with Kovenant, like so:

```
fun promiseFunc1() : Promise<Int, Exception> {
    return Promise.of(1)
}

fun promiseFunc2() : Promise<Int, Exception> {
    return Promise.of(2)
}

fun promiseCaller() {
    promiseFunc1() then { it: Int ->
        promiseFunc2()
    } then { it: Int ->
        // Compilation error: it is not not an integer
    }
}
```

It seems that `then` in Kovenant returns the value as is. How do I get the actual integer from `promiseFunc2`? The only solution I got is using the `get()` function, like so:

```
    promiseFunc1() then { it: Int ->
        promiseFunc2().get()
    } then { it: Int ->
        // it is now an integer
    }
```

However, since `get()` blocks the thread it only works if `then` is running on a background thread (which it does), still, it feels like a hack.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `Promise<Promise<Int, Exception>, Exception>` type when you return another promise from the lambda passed to `then`. Therefore in the next `then` the argument `it` has type `Promise<Int,...>` instead of `Int`.

In order to flatten promise you can use [`unwrap`](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/api/core_usage/#unwrap) function, which converts `Promise<Promise<V>>` into `Promise<V>`. Then your example would look like:

```
promiseFunc1().then { it: Int ->
   promiseFunc2()
}.unwrap()
.then { it: Int ->
   // it is now an integer
}
```

If that combination of `then {}.unwrap()` appears often in your code, you can use its shorthand [`bind`](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/api/functional_usage/#bind) from `kovenant-functional`:

```
promiseFunc1() bind { it: Int ->
   promiseFunc2()
} then { it: Int ->
   // it is now an integer
}
```